# cannot convert value of type [Struct] to type [string] in coercion swift

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I got this error:

> cannot convert value of type [Destinos] to type [String] in coercion swift

I have this Struct:

`public struct Destinos: Data {
    public var idDestino : Int?
    public var desDestino : String?
}`

and this:

`var listado = [Destinos]()
listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 1, desDestino: "Asunción"))
listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 2, desDestino: "Miami"))`

then:

```
var ListaDeDestinos = [String]()
```

so my error appears in this line:

```
ListaDeDestinos = DestinoLista.listado as [String]
```

What is wrong here? can help me please? i´m don´t find anything like this in the forums

Edit 
all my code:

```
import UIKit
```

class Api {

```
let Presentador: DestinoPresenter! // referenciamos la clase DestinoPresenter en una variable local

init(Present: DestinoPresenter){ // constuctor: inicializamos la variable Presentador y creamos una copia de la clase DestinoPresenter
    Presentador = Present
}

var listado = [Destinos]()


func GetDestinos(){


    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 1, desDestino: "Asunción"))
    listado.append(Destinos(idDestino: 2, desDestino: "Miami"))


    print(listado)

}
```

}

class DestinoPresenter {

```
let mview: ViewController // referenciamos la clase DestinoPresenter en una variable local

init(view: ViewController) { //construnctor
    mview = view
}

var ArrayAutoComplete = [String]()
var ListaDeDestinos = [String]()
fileprivate var DestinoLista: Api!


func searchDestinos(_ substring: String) {

    ArrayAutoComplete.removeAll() //cada vez que llamemos a esta funcion, limpiamos la variable ArrayAutoComplete del TableView

    DestinoLista = Api(Present: self)
    DestinoLista.GetDestinos()
```

//        ListaDeDestinos = [(DestinoLista.listado as AnyObject) as! String]
        ListaDeDestinos = DestinoLista.listado as [String]

```
    for key in ListaDeDestinos {

        let myString:NSString! = key as NSString

        if (myString.lowercased.contains(substring.lowercased())) {
            print(myString.contains(myString as String) ? "yep" : "nope")
            ArrayAutoComplete.append(key)

        }
    }

    mview.mostarResultados(ArrayResultados: ArrayAutoComplete) //llamamos a la función y le pasamos como parametro ArrayAutoComplete

}
```

}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField! = nil
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! = nil

var autoCompleteDestino: [String] = []

fileprivate var DestinoP: DestinoPresenter!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //LEER: pasando como referencia tu vista
    DestinoP = DestinoPresenter(view: self)


    title = "Texto predecible"
```

//        DestinoP.getDestinos()
//        DestinoP.ListarDestinos()

```
}
func mostarResultados(ArrayResultados: [String]) {

    autoCompleteDestino = ArrayResultados
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

```
public func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let substring = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    DestinoP.searchDestinos(substring)

    return true

}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    //    Completa el string encontrado en el tableView segun caracter ingresado en el textField
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        let index = indexPath.row as Int

```
    cell.textLabel!.text = autoCompleteDestino[index]

    return cell
}
```

}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return autoCompleteDestino.count

}
//    selecciona el resultado desde el tableView para completar en el textField.
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)!

    textField.text = selectedCell.textLabel!.text!

}
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: hi!  
I am trying to store the result (listado) of the list in my var (ListaDeDestinos) and then show (...) 
If you are not understanding I can give you the complete code

Comment: I think you need to loop through listado and pull out only the desDestino member variables. Right now you are telling the compiler to make a struct a string, which it doesn't know how to do

Comment: A `Destinos` is not a `String`. You need some way to convert a `Destinos` to a `String` (implementing `CustomStringConvertible` is a popular approach, but there are many other ways to do it). The fundamental question is what you want the "string version" of a `Destinos` to be. You have to define that yourself. If you just want "something usable for debugging", then use `String(describing:)` to create string version of each element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wanted the string member variable of each listados object, do:

```
for object in DestinoLista.listados {
    ListaDeDestinos.append(object.desDestino)
}
```

Comment: Yes..!! this works!                                                                                            for object in DestinoLista.listado {
            ListaDeDestinos.append(object.desDestino!)
        }

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want "the string version of `Destinos`" to be. If you don't really care, and just want "something usable for debugging," then map it to `String(describing:)`:

```
let listaDeDestinos = listado.map(String.init(describing:))
```